# Define In-App-Purchase Type

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am looking for clarification of what type of In-App purchase would the following fall under according to Apple (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Products.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH2-SW2):

A monthly video subscription service that delivers rich content only available on the application.

Do I need to offer the ability to restore purchases? If a user subscribes in March is it okay to give full access historically? If a user joins, cancels and joins, can the history cover the gap? Reading the documentation it is not very clear.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need the ability to restore a purchase.

The rest is a business decision and is entirely up to you. Apple may quibble if you don't make what you're selling clear but the details are yours to decide.